# Who are the top users in our tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, data-explorer

After a recent discussion over in TREU with another user I wondered if there was a way to find out who the top users in our tags are.

I know we can do this by going to the Top Users tab of the tags page but is there a faster way? I imagine this can be done in SEDE.

Comment: Surely going to the Top Users tab of the tags page is faster than using SEDE?

Comment: @Randal'Thor It took me around 90 mins using SEDE, if you can do that quicker for all 2934 tags and keep the list in an easy to see place and what not be my guest and I'll gladly be proven wrong

Comment: @Randal'Thor Oh and as mentioned my query takes into account answer count which the top users page does not.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:** Here are the queries:

- [Top users in a tag by score and answer count](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/912558/top-users-in-a-tag-by-score-and-answer-count)
- [Top user in all tags by score and answer count](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/912557/top-user-in-all-tags-by-score-and-answer-count)
- [Tags where specified user is top by score and answer count](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/912566/tags-where-specified-user-is-top-by-score-and-answer-count)

---

This can be done using SEDE! However, to be clear that there is a slight limitation in that SEDE only updates once every week.

> **How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**
>
> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC
>
> <sub>[Data Explorer, Using Data Explorer, Frequently Asked Questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)</sub>

I have used a query previously that tracked gold tag badge progress. Before we get in to the queries the following is important.

- They are different to "Top Users" as it takes into answer count as well.
- They don't take into account question count/score... this may be desirable to someone
- The factor to make the score and count be more evenly matched may need tailoring slightly.

With some slight modifications to it I have come up with the following query for: [Top users in a tag by score and answer count](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/912558/top-users-in-a-tag-by-score-and-answer-count). The results of this query for our top tag [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) are:

[image: Top users in the story identification tag]

Modifying this with the help of a user on SO we get the following query which brings back the top user in every tag, in the case of a draw it will bring back all top users: [Top user in all tags by score and answer count](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/912557/top-user-in-all-tags-by-score-and-answer-count). It currently looks like the following at the top:

[image: Top user in all tags]

And then for a bit of fun I modified it slightly so that it takes a user id as input and tells you what tags that user is top in: [Tags where specified user is top by score and answer count](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/912566/tags-where-specified-user-is-top-by-score-and-answer-count). Running it for our current top user, Valorum, we see, this brings back an impressive 642 rows:

[image: Tags where Valorum is the top user]

Comment: Why do you divide the Sum(a.score) by 10.0 in those queries?

Comment: @rene Because I want the answer count to play a part in the rankings, if I didn't factor it down somehow there'd be no point in looking at answer count. I picked 10 arbitrarily after a quick look at some users score to answer ratio but it probably wants tweaking a bit.

Comment: That makes sense, yes. I was somehow confused that you maybe mixed score and reputation (as you get 10 rep for an upvote) and wanted to normalize that or so. We're all good then. Cheers!